# Implement strstr

Tags: c++, strstr

I am trying to write the strstr function from scratch.  I went through my code line by line in the debugger and it works fine.  However, it is not saving the start of the substring its searching for properly.  And, therefore, it is not returning it properly.  I do not have much programming experience so my code is a little messy and convoluted. However, it does work for the most part.  Here is my code below (commented for my professor and for you all to see what I did). (also, my professor has already expressed his acceptance of the goto function)

```
char *strgstr(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    //I went through this function line by line with the debugger
    //The only problem with it is when I go to save the location of the
    //substring in str1.  
    //I posted a question on stackoverflow and I was able to get it to compile
    //but it still doesn't save and return properly.  The rest of the function works.
    int len_str1=strlen(str1);
    int len_str2=strlen(str2);
    char *save_str=NULL;
    int i=0;
    for(; i<len_str1; i++)
    {
there:
        if(str1[i]==str2[0])            //checks if this is the beginning of str2
        {
            save_str=(char*)str1[i];    //This is where the problem is. 
            int j=0;                    //start at beginning of str2
            for(;i<len_str1;i++)        //index str1
            {
                if(j<len_str2)          //checks if we've finished searching str2
                {
                    if(str1[i]!=str2[j])
                    {
                        goto there;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return save_str;    //does not return properly.  I can't figure out how to save a particular point in the index to a pointer. 
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't str1[i] dereference from the original pointer, then your casting a char to a char * ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line you've written as

```
save_str=(char*)str1[i];    //This is where the problem is.
```

should be (for example)

```
save_str = str1 + i;
```

Your original version is treating the numerical value of the character as a pointer, which is completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need such complex code?

```
const char *strgcstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)        
{
 while(*haystack!=0)
 {
   if( (*haystack == *needle) &&
       (strncmp(haystack, needle, strlen(needle)) == 0) )
   return haystack;
  haystack++;
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can't this examine "characters" off the end of `haystack` in the `strncmp()` call, and therefore risk a segfault/bus error (what if the end of `haystack` is the top of the address space?) Just saying, I think this is a little *too* simple.

Comment: No, `strncmp` will stop at the end of `haystack`. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/ : "This function starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ, *until a terminating null-character is reached*, or until num characters match in both strings, *whichever happens first*." (Emphasis mine). However, it does look like it will incorrectly return a match if the haystack ends with a prefix of the needle.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They haystack cannot end with a prefix of the needle. The haystack always ends with a zero byte, since this is the definition of a C-style string. And a prefix of the needle cannot contain a zero byte, since by the definition of a C-style string, a zero byte ends it. (Test it if you don't believe me.)

Comment: I meant a prefix of the needle immediately before the zero byte, of course. But I suppose it will compare the zero byte to the nonzero byte in the needle...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Exactly. We exclude the zero byte in the needle from having to match because that's the semantics of `strstr`. But the zero byte in the haystack is part of its data and we don't exclude it. We don't have to do anything special because that's part of the semantics of `strncmp`. However, it is a bit of a trap for someone who attempts to replace the call to `strncmp` with their own implementation of `strncmp` that doesn't correctly implement this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Java code for strstr

```
class Solution {
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    String res ="";
    int pos = 0;
    if(needle.length() == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(haystack.equals(needle)){
        return 0;
    }
    if (needle.length()>haystack.length()||haystack.length() == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i =0; i<haystack.length();i++){
            if(haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(0)){
                if(i+needle.length() <= haystack.length()){
                res = haystack.substring(i,i+(needle.length()));
                if (res.equals(needle)){
                pos = i;
                return pos;
                }
        }
                else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        return -1;

}
}
```